# Python coding error, My Window is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am new to coding and have been going through the raspberry pi education manual. I have uploaded PySide for Python and tested it to make sure it is working properly.[Picture of Code I entered from manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlJl4.png)... When I run the program shown in the image I get a " NameError: name 'My Window' is not defined ". I am certain I have not made a typo and have posted this code verbatim (well I thought I did :( ... ). I apologize if this is similar to questions asked before; I did an advanced search on google and could not find any results for this specific issue and I am fixated on resolving this issue and move forward in the manual. Thanks, Mitchell B. 
Here is the code pasted:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Window Events')

        self.label = QLabel('Read me', self)

        button = QPushButton('Push Me', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        """ Update the text when the button is clicked """
        self.label.setText("Clicked")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """
        Update the text when the (tracked) mouse moves over MyWindow
        """
        self.label.setText(str(event.x()) + "," + str(event.y()))

    application = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = MyWindow()

    widget.show()

    application.exec_()
```

The full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Gettingartistic.py", line 5, in <module> class MyWindow(QWidget): File "/home/pi/Gettingartistic.py", line 44, in MyWindow widget = MyWindow() NameError: name 'MyWindow' is not defined
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to paste the code?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Gettingartistic.py", line 5, in <module>
    class MyWindow(QWidget):
  File "/home/pi/Gettingartistic.py", line 44, in MyWindow
    widget = MyWindow()
NameError: name 'MyWindow' is not defined

Comment: Did you mean to dedent everything after `application = ...`? It's currently part of your class definition, at which point, yes, the class doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I should have dedented the last four lines one further, sorry it was a very beginner question. I just started messing with python last night. Thanks for the quick responses everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your

```
application = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = MyWindow()

widget.show()

application.exec_()
```

part should be deindented. It's currently part of the class definition, remember that in python, indents are important.

As of right now, since that part is part of the `MyWindow()` class definition, the class `MyWindow` would not have been created yet on the statement `widget = MyWindow()`, so it'd throw an exception.

Comment: From the picture he gave I think it's a copy-paste mistake

Comment: :/ based on the error message, this seems like exactly the issue though. Well, it's a very beginner mistake

Comment: Agreed, well played, I was too confident in the given picture :(

Comment: It was a very beginner mistake :). But thank you for your very quick response.